# What would Voyager's mission have been if they hadn't gotten stuck in the Delta quadrant?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

I know their first mission was to track down Chakotay and his crew, but otherwise what was Voyager's intended mission beyond that?

Comment: To explore strange new worlds, to seek out new life and new civilizations, to boldly go where no one has gone before?

Comment: Honestly this is an excellent question and one that I hadn't given much thought to

Comment: @LogicDictates Maybe, but in an early episode doesn't someone say (I paraphrase) “Starfleet practices won't work here, we're out where no man has gone before!” ?

Comment: @Valorum personally, I don't agree. It seems very clear to me that after finding the Maquis the mission is over. Either another mission will be assigned to the same crew (after Parris is returned to his confinement and the Maquis dealt with), or *Voyager* will be given a different crew and mission and the crew from the show will get new assignments.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Sure. And the question is asking what those plans are

Comment: @ToddWilcox Valorum is correct. Some Starfleet ships are given long-standing orders (the various Enterprises come to mind). My question was about Voyager. It was clearly commissioned for a reason, it has advanced technologies that other ships don't have, so what was the intention?

Comment: I agree with @Valorum that this is an excellent question. I never thought about it, and I doubt that viewers were supposed to think about it. After all, it didn't matter after finding the Maquis and the show became a [Lost in Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_in_Space) scenario. At that point I started concentrating on whether Janeway's hair was real.

Comment: @Wastrel Star Trek viewers wouldn't think about it because starships have always had multiple missions - and Voyager would have presumably done the same mix of exploration and frontier patrol as other ships.  I suspect the only mission that can be ruled out is ultra deep space exploration- which is ironically what it got.  From the original series writers guide "ON PATROL OF A SECTION OF OUR GALAXY - our vessel representing Earth and the Fed. (assisting colonists, aiding in sci. exploration, putting down conflicts, helping those in distress, regulating trade, engaging in diplomatic missions.

Comment: Possibly this should be *hadn't have gotten stuck*, but I think that's enough modals already.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Intrepid](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Intrepid_class) class of ships is designed for 'long-term exploration'

> **NEELIX:** *Voyager's an Intrepid class starship with a crew of one hundred and forty six, designed for long-term exploration. I thought we'd start with a tour of our primary systems. First stop, Engineering*
>
> <sub><sup>**[VOY: Someone To Watch Over Me](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/521.htm)**</sup></sub>

That being said, Voyager doesn't seem to have a *designated* mission in mind, beyond their present, short-term mission to track down the Maquis. Janeway seems pretty confident that they're going to return to Earth afterwards (in time for her puppies to be born) and then get a new assignment in due course.

---

The [Star Trek: The Official Starships Collection #6](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Official_Starships_Collection#:%7E:text=English-,Star%20Trek%3A%20The%20Official%20Starships%20Collection,-SIGN%20IN%20TO) has this to say on the subject.

> **Voyager was designed as a multi-mission exploration vessel that would
> be supported by regular visits to Starbases**, and, although she
> represented the cutting edge of Starfleet technology, she was far from
> the ideal vessel for such a massive journey.

Comment: I suggest readers consider the source for the Neelix quote and who he is speaking too.  In-universe an Intrepid class is about the same size as a Constitution class.  There are obviously plenty of situations where a starship can make a difference regardless of size just as the original Enterprise did.

Answer (score 3):

Janeway was a scientist,  thus starfleet gave her a state of the art, long range but moderate endurance/time exploration vessel.
[image]

As well as provide a platform for extended scientific/exploration survey and scouting of new planets, the Intrepid class was a modest sized multi-mission surveyor. Judging by the fact Voyager was FASTEST when fresh out of drydock, and having Ability to land on planetary surface, Intrepid class was also to Aid in colonization and territorial acquisition of new M-class (Earth-esque habitable) worlds to it's portfolio. In other words "Show the Flag, in deep space"

The Intrepid was also a test bed for various technologies.

- Extensive Automation: Mitigating huge logistical crew requirements of ships normally need 200-300 people. Thus saving lives in wartime environment where crew casualties
- Emergency Medical hologram: Free up manpower for essential duties while doctors focus on triage around the ship
- Bio-neural circuits: Again "Data organization" not specificied how this is better than conventional circuits. More that design software in the packs prioritize information
- Variable geometry Pylons: Likely response to test better HIGH speed warp velocities in shaky or questionable subspace environments. As well as "Environmentally Friendly" warp propulsion

Unlike other Explorers, this vessel wasn't designed for grandiose 5 year mission or Galaxy-class style multi-year public/private, ambassadorial/diplomatic. Being roughly similar size to Kirk's Connie Enterprise [image]

Missions undoubtedly would be "Exploration" charting new star systems, it's advanced sensors for anomalies, unusual features.

Comment: What is the source of the images, if they are not your work?

Comment: Give it a few years.  A starship with landing gear might be nice and advanced - but can it maneuver under water like a starship toy in J.J.'s bathtub?